# Why were the bodies positioned in this way?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-strangers

At the end of *The Strangers* (2008), the body of the main woman character, Kristen, was placed next to the body of the friend, Mike. The body of the main male character, James, was placed in the other room.

Was there a reason for this?

I know it's very conspiratorial of me, but is there any chance Kristen could have cheated on James with Mike and didn't want to get engaged to James because of it? And perhaps that was part of the motivation for the "strangers"' attack?

I doubt I'm right, but I just can't figure out why the body placements would have been like that, in the final scene that the movie decided to end on.